# Type mismatch error when using win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch

Tags: python, com

I'm trying to interact with the COM interface of a proprietary application using the win32com module. I can connect to the interface using the dynamic proxy (win32com.client.Dispatch), which appears to work. However, it would be useful if I could use a static proxy, not least because it populates the help() pages.

I can interact normally with the dynamic proxy:

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> aqt = win32com.client.Dispatch("Aquator.Application")
>>> db = aqt.LoadDatabase(Folder=r"D:\Shared", Name="AquatorExcel.mdb")
>>> db.Name
u'D:\\Shared\\AquatorExcel.mdb'
>>> db.GetProjectList()
(1, (3,), (u'A simple model',))
```

But when I use the static proxy generated using EnsureDispatch or the makepy script, I get this error:

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> aqt = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Aquator.Application")
>>> db.Name
u'D:\\Shared\\AquatorExcel.mdb'
>>> db = aqt.LoadDatabase(Folder=r"D:\Shared", Name="AquatorExcel.mdb")
>>> db.GetProjectList()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Pythonxy\Pythonxy 2.7\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32c
om\gen_py\AE9A7F2A-5DD7-4658-B55C-216CAD680889x0x4x3\_Database.py", line 70, in
GetProjectList
    , NameList)
  File "C:\Program Files\Pythonxy\Pythonxy 2.7\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32c
om\client\__init__.py", line 456, in _ApplyTypes_
    self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 1)
```

I'm fairly new to COM in general, so I really have no idea where to go from here. What is causing this error and how can I avoid it?

Comment: `GetProjectList` expects two arguments, the first argument is a dynamic array of `long`, the second argument is a dynamic array of `string`.  How this translates into COM I have no idea.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski In VBA, GetProjectList takes two arguments used to return the results. However, Python just returns them like a normal function. If I pass two empty lists it seems to work correctly, i.e. `db.GetProjectList([],[])`. I don't understand why there is a different between the dynamic/static proxies.

Comment: I don't either.  I just happened to read the examples I could find online.  Since it accepts empty Python lists to return the results, you should name those lists before passing them.  That way you will have access to them.  `a,b = [],[]; db.GetProjectList(a, b)`.